# Why serving static file in production, using django it's discouraged?

Tags: django, docker, microservices, gunicorn, static-files

I have developed a web application that uses (obviously) some static files, in order to deploy it, I've chosen to serve the files with the WSGI interpreter and use for the job gunicorn behind a firewall and a reverse proxy.

My application uses whitenoise to server staticfiles: Everything works fine and I don't have any issue regarding the performances...but, really, I can't understand WHY the practice to serve those static files using directly the WSGI interpreter it's discouraged ([LINK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)), says:

> This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment strategies...

I mean, my service it's a collection of microservices: DB-Frontend-Services-Etc...If I need to scale them, I can do this without any problem and, in addition, using this philosophy, I'm not worried about the footprint of my microservices: for me, this seems logical, but maybe, for the rest of the world this is a completely out-of-mind strategy.

Answer (score 3):

You've misinterpreted that documentation. It's fine to use Whitenoise to serve static files; that is entirely what it's for. What is not a good idea is to use that internal Django function to do so, since it is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Three reasons why I personally serve static from CDN,

1- You are using up bandwidth from your app server and loosing time getting these static files instead of throwing the load to CDN to handle all that. (WhiteNoise should though eliminate that)

2- Some hosting services like AWS will charge you for extra traffic in/out, while you can use cheaper services like Cloudfront and a S3 bucket.

3- I like to keep my app servers for app purposes only, and utilize each service for its job only, this helps me in debugging and reducing my failure points.

On the other hand though, serving static from app server with something like WhiteNoise is much much easier than configuring your CDN.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "why I don't serve static from CDN" doesn't match the reasons. You mean the opposite?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite ok when you use Whitenoise because:

1. Whitenoise is exactly made for this purpose and therefore efficient
2. It'll set the HTTP response headers correctly so clients cache the files.

But think of it this way: Instead of serving 1 or 2 requests per web page, you'll often get 10x more requests (usually web pages will request a bunch of images, one or more css files, a couple of js files...). Meaning you have to scale your application server to serve 10x more traffic on average than if you leave the job to a CDN.

By the way, I've written a [tutorial](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2019/01/02/deploying-your-django-static-files-aws-partnbsp2) on this topic which may help.